# How to connect to remote mysql from my google app engine standard project?

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Currently I am using the native Cloud SQL instance that is getting billed against the same project. However to cut some cost, I intend to shift the databases to my other mysql sitting at my other hosting. But I need to put a static IP on the allowed hosts in order to make it work. I added the 4 hosts that they make you add as A records to point the domain. But it didn't work. I read about Sockets API.. but didn't really get it. It's confusing. How to make it work? putting those 4 IP in makes it workable once or twice randomly when once of those provided IP is active I guess but whenever some other IP from the pool gets active, it doesn't work!

Comment: This may be a question for tech support at your "other hosting." Many hosting providers prevent access to MySQL from outside their environments unless you activate it.

Comment: Google should be able to give you a list of ranges of IP addresses you can get your "other hosting" to put in a whitelist for port 3306 (MySQL) access.

Comment: @O.Jones mysql the 'other hosting' works fine with my workbench on my windows desktop with a static public ip

Comment: Yes that is what I am unable to find.. I couldn't find any documentation on how to get the IP(s).. for compute engine, there's option for external static IP.. but for appengine, I am not sure where to find them

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Serverless VPC Access with VPC Access Connector as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/connecting-vpc)?

You should be able to use the VPC Access Connector Source IP CIDR range  at your MySql end as allowed IP list.

However you must ensure the connection is secure with a VPN or interconnect.

Comment: I never bothered to take a look at it since it was luxury for the time being. Also due to some performance issues, we had to move the apps from GAE.